# Protect routes from users who are not signed in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, routes

I'm using Rails 4 and Devise to authenticate users. Once a user logs in, they are redirected to a sinatra app. I need the route to that page to be protected from unsigned-in users.

So the route I need to prevent users from visiting if they are not signed in is /kibana

Here is my routes files:

```
  devise_for :user
  root 'pages#home'

  mount Kibana::Sinatra::Web => '/kibana', :trailing_slash => true
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

EDIT here is my ApplicationController file

```
 protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :check_user
  private
  def check_user
    if request.fullpath =~ /kibana/ && !user_signed_in? 
       authenticate :user do
       end
    end
  end
```

Yet, not the result I need. When I visit localhost:3000 it redirects me to the user login with the note that I need to be logged in, but when I visit /kibana/ it just shows it without having to be logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>More or less this way:</strike>

```
class ApplicationController

  before_filter :check_user

  private

  def check_user
    if !current_user && request.fullpath =~ /kibana/
      redirect_to your_app_login_url
    end
  end

end
```

Edit:

It looks like I was wrong, within your routes.rb:

```
authenticate :user do
  mount Kibana::Sinatra::Web => '/kibana', :trailing_slash => true
end
```

Comment: Do I have to use controllers to protect the route?

Comment: `routes.rb` gives only the definition of routing of your application. You do not have any access to the request here.

Comment: I see. I tried your solution but I can still visit /kibana/ without having to sign in.

Comment: Well, perhaps the condition does not match, debug it. For not logged user it should match.

Comment: And do I need to create a new controller or in the Application controller?

Comment: I've just edited my question adding my new controller, could you kindly check it?

Comment: just go with `authenticate :user do
  mount Kibana::Sinatra::Web => '/kibana'
end`

Comment: @andreydeineko hi thank you for your answer. I should add this to my routes file, correct? That worked for me. I've already tried it this morning and it didn't work BUT For some MAGICAL reason, it's working now. Thanks.

Comment: thank you so much, I've accepted your answer. @andreydeineko I apologize for not accepting your answer as it appears Blelump have edited his answer before. Thank you both.